# How can I create an HTML text input that validates URLs as well as anchor links?

Tags: html, anchor

I've got an input field of type text where I'd like to allow the user to enter full URLs as well as anchor links that start with "#". I've got a regex that works as expected on regex101.com but doesn't work within the HTML code.

Here's my HTML code with the regex I'm trying to use:

```
<input type="text" pattern="https?://.+|^[#]">
<input type="submit">
```

This regex works as expected on regex101 but it the HTML it matches URLs but not the anchor links. I'd appreciate any guidance with this!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `type="url"` instead of `type="text"`

Comment: That won't validate anchor links that start with "#" I'm afraid. Tried that already.

Comment: @ayushn21 just validate manually using `js` or `jQuery` without depending on browser implementation.